# Can we implement our python project in Python Virtual Environment for production environment?

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv, development-environment, python-venv

**Problem:**
We have two different python service which should be ran in a single server. Where we have a dependency clash. Say **Project A** needs module - older version while **Project B** needs the same module but with newer version.

To isolate we found **Python Virtual Environment** will solve this issue.

> But the real question for me is the **Virtual environment** will be stable
>   and accepted on the production level usage.

Or Is there any other way we can approach for the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can
You can create virtual environment for first service where python version will be different and for second service, you can use different python version.
you can set these environment in running path of your services (for example in supervisor which we use for running process)

> [program:service1]
>   command=path_to_virtualenv_for_service1 python service1.py
>
> [program:service2]
>   command=path_to_virtualenv_for_service2 python service2.py

Answer (score 0):

It is perfectly acceptable to use a virtual environment in production. In fact, it is often encouraged as it will ensure that any updates to the Python packages for one of the projects will not break the other.

A good alternative is to use separate Docker containers for each of the projects.